# How to use Android's DownloadManager over P2P connection

Tags: android, android-wifi, p2p, wifi-direct, android-download-manager

From an Android application, I would like to use DownloadManager to download files from a peer which is connected using P2P (Wi-Fi Direct).
However, I found that unless the tablet/phone is connected to a WiFi network, DownloadManager will refuse to download over the P2P connection. It will output an error claiming "NO CONNECTION". If both Wi-Fi and P2P are connected, I can successfully download over the P2P connection.

Here's a sample code:

```
String url = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip";
String localFile = "5MB.zip";

DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |  DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
request.setTitle("test.txt");
request.setDescription("Testing DownloadManager -- 5MB.zip");
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, null, localFile);

DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
long downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Now, I'm not sure if I'm just not using it correctly, or whether it's an unsupported feature. I'm willing to change Android's codebase if needed in order to get it to work (but I can't choose an alternative to DownloadManager).

Inspecting Android's code, it seems that the method checkCanUseNetwork() will return "NO_CONNECTION" because it gets a null NetworkInfo from mSystemFacade. See:

/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadInfo.java

Further investigation hints to a "problem" in ConnectivityService. While it sets its mActiveDefaultNetwork to the correct type when Wi-Fi network is connected, it won't do anything when P2P is connected.

/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java

I'm using Nexus 4 with Android 5.0.1, but I've seen the same issue with KitKat 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove following line of code, it will work.

"request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |  DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);"